# OsmDroid slow overlay drawing

Tags: android, maps, overlay, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I crate my custom Overlay to draw on canvas, but the method Draw is called many times.
I have many entities to draw and this slows the map.
How can I draw on my overlay only when the map ends its drawing ? Or how can I optimized Draw Overlay call's?